# Can I have a space in username that I use for logging into Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I try to run query

```
CREATE USER `Mark Johnanssen`
```

I get the error message `Invalid user name.`

I suspect that the reason for this is space in username since `CREATE USER MarkJohnanssen` works.

When I run `SHOW CONFIG;` I get the following settings related to users:

```
name,default_value,current_value,description
flag_file,,/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf,load flags from file
auth_module_executable,,,Absolute path to the auth module executable that should be used.
auth_module_timeout_ms,10000,10000,Timeout (in milliseconds) used when waiting for a response from the auth module.
password_encryption_algorithm,bcrypt,bcrypt,The password encryption algorithm used for authentication.
audit_buffer_flush_interval_ms,200,200,Interval (in milliseconds) used for flushing the audit log buffer.
audit_buffer_size,100000,100000,Maximum number of items in the audit log buffer.
audit_enabled,false,false,Set to true to enable audit logging.
auth_password_permit_null,true,true,Set to false to disable null passwords.
auth_password_strength_regex,.+,.+,The regular expression that should be used to match the entire entered password to ensure its strength.
auth_user_or_role_name_regex,[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-@]+,[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-@]+,Set to the regular expression that each user or role name must fulfill.
```

Comment: The absence of a space in that `auth_user_or_role_name_regex` looks like something you could try to fix.

Comment: @Botje it seems that you are spot on :) I've run the Memgraph using docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name memgraph2 memgraph/memgraph-mage --auth-user-or-role-name-regex="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+\-@ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+\-@ ]+".  I can see that new Reges should kick in, but I get the message "Custom user/role regex is a Memgraph Enterprise feature." but this is beyond the scope of my question. Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Memgraph has to be run with flag for a Regex that includes the space, e.g. `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name memgraph2 memgraph/memgraph-mage --auth-user-or-role-name-regex="[a-zA-Z0-9_.+\-@ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.+\-@ ]+"`